# Htaccess working on localhost but not on server : error 500

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !kaomadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !article
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !commentaire
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ page/page_url?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !kaomadmin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !commentaire
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !article/ajout
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !article/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !article/modification
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ article/article_url?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It works on localhost, but not on any of my online websites... I saw that httpd.conf AllowOverride must be set to all but i don't have that permission... and i don't see mod_rewrite on my php_info... maybe i missed something?

I tried with some htaccess tester and it works too ! I think my only problems are servers restriction... any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you're using some shared hosting solition; in that case, it's probably impossible without help from the system administrator. You could ask, but you should expect a no.

Comment: I'm using hosting solutions like 1&1, online.net, ovh yeah... is there a way to get through ?

Comment: Add some random junk text at the top of the file and see if you get an Internal Server Error. If you do, then `.htaccess` is working. Then, to test `mod_rewrite`, add this just below `RewriteEngine On`: `RewriteRule ^test$ http://google.com/ [R=302,L]` and navigate to `/test` on your domain. **Note:** I'm sure that 1&1 supports `.htaccess` out of the box, and `mod_rewrite` should be enabled. Not sure about online.net.

Comment: So .htaccess is working and mod_rewrite is on, but i still can't do my things (which is simply rename some urls...)